# Given a line segment of points ABCD find what is required below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

On a straight line, consider the points A. B, C and D in consecutive form
so that they form a harmonic quatern; over AB, BC and AD, their midpoints are marked P, Q and R respectively.
Calculate $\frac{AP}{BQ}-\frac{AQ}{CR}$ (Answer:$\frac{3}{2}$)

My progress:
Harmonic Quatern implies $\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AD}{CD}$ and $\frac{2}{AC}=\frac{1}{AB}+\frac{1}{AD}$

Let $AB=a, BC=b, CD = c$

$AP =BQ = \frac{a}{2}, PQ=QR = \frac{b}{2}$

$AR=RD= \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

$\frac{AP}{PQ} = \frac{\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{b}{2}}=\frac{a}{b} \implies \frac{AP}{BQ}-\frac{AQ}{CR}=\frac{AB}{BC}-\frac{AQ}{CR}=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{AQ}{QR}(I)$

$AQ = AB+BQ = a+\frac{b}{2}=\frac{2a+b}{2}\\
CR = AR-AC = \frac{a+b+c}{2}-(a+b)=\frac{-a-b+c}{2}$

From(I): $\frac{a}{b}-(\frac{2a+b}{-a-b+c})=\frac{-a^2-ab+ac-2ab-b^2}{b(-a-b+c)}=\frac{-a^2-3ab+ac-b^2}{b(-a-b+c)}$

...I couldn't resolve...

Comment: Hint: harmonic quatern implies that $b(a+b+c)=ac$

Comment: Also, in your line 5, it is $AP/{\color{red}{B}}Q$ not $AP/PQ$. /you have a typo there.

Comment: I checked this problem using geogebra and it tuens out $AP/BP-AQ/CR$ is varying... this problem is false. But here is a trivial counterexample: making $B$ close to the midpoint of $AC$, so $AP/BP$ goes to $1$ and  $AQ/CR$ goes to zero. It is not $3/2$. When in doubt or when stuck, you can check this problem yourself whether is correct by listing some examples. If the problem is false, then hooray, you don't need to think about this problem anymore.

Comment: @JetfiRex  Thank you very much for the comments.. I also think there is a problem in the wording of the question